# VS2017: Don't show Nuget version compatibility warnings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm suppressing the NU1608 warning when building my code (the versions I have for my components have been tested and work as desired together) but Visual Studio still shows little warning icons on my dependencies.

[image]

Is there a way to suppress this annotation as well?  It's distracting and I don't want to see this warning... and frankly it's all over the place.  The dotnet core approach to versioned packages virtually guarantees that you'll have *some* version discrepancies all the time.

Comment: How are you suppressing the warnings? I am trying but the warnings still show up in the Error List

Comment: @Peter you can suppress it in the csproj file.  See https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5769 for an idea how to do this.